# Extending $firebaseArray to use $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

2nd EDIT: The issue now is not being able to pass in $scope.hashtag to the hashFilter callback function. So close!

PROGRESS EDIT: I'm really close to cracking this but can't figure out how to re-rerun the filter when $scope changes. $watch does not seem to work.

Here is a plnkr with the new `$extend` `$firebaseArray` example: http://plnkr.co/edit/RUwL0Cstm9c8jhI2VGi9?p=preview

I just need to re-rerun this when the $scope.hashtag changes.

```
//Factory
app.factory('FilteredArray', function($firebaseArray){
    var FilteredArray = $firebaseArray.$extend({
      $$added: function(snap) {
         var rec = $firebaseArray.prototype.$$added.call(this, snap);
         if( !this.filterFn || this.filterFn(rec) ) {
           return rec;
         }
       },
       filter: function(filterFn) {
          this.filterFn = filterFn;
        }
    });

    return function(listRef){
      return new FilteredArray(listRef);
    };

  });

//Controller
var ref = new Firebase("https://plnkr.firebaseio.com/things");

  $scope.things = new FilteredArray(ref);
  $scope.things.filter(hashFilter);

  $scope.hashtag = 'something';

  function hashFilter(rec) {
    console.log('hashFilter ran');
    var result = false;
    angular.forEach(rec, function(value, key, obj) {
      if (obj.hashtag) {
        if (obj.hashtag == $scope.hashtag) {
          console.log(obj.hashtag == $scope.hashtag);
          result = true;
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

ORIGINAL POST:
I'm trying to `$filter` a `$firebaseArray` from my controller but cannot get it working.

In the view, everything works great like this (simplified):

```
ng-repeat = "thing in things | filter: 'something'"
```

Unfortunately, in the controller:

```
$scope.things = $filter('filter')(theUnfilteredFirebaseArray, 'something');
```

does not work. I think that has to do with `$firebaseArray` but I am not sure.

The data structure looks like this:

```
things: {
    thingID1: {
      something: 'value';
    },
    thingID2: {
     something: 'value'
    },
   ...
}
```

I stumbled upon this post by Kato but I can't figure out how to actually apply the filter here: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/bee266e31aa60cb0eed6

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here's a link to the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RUwL0Cstm9c8jhI2VGi9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the data isn't loaded yet. Try this:

```
var theUnfilteredFirebaseArray = $firebaseArray(...);

theUnfilteredFirebaseArray.$loaded(function(){
    $scope.things = $filter('filter')(theUnfilteredFirebaseArray, 'something');
});
```

Why are you filtering in the controller? Doing it in the dom means you don't have to do this.

Comment: I'm filtering in the controller because I am using 'ui-sortable' to sort the list and it uses the $index value of each item to do sorting. Using $loaded generally works but now $scope.things isn't available to the rest of the controller to do things like $save, $add, $remove. I tried moving the $filter and loading to a service and then call it but it shows up as undefined.

Comment: Can you paste your controller and what else you're trying to do?

Comment: Yea, I can make a plnkr to go over just the specific things I am trying to do. I think this approach in general wont' work because the $filter service returns a new array that is not a $firebaseArray so $add, $remove, etc. won't work. I need to filter at another level.

Comment: Can you wire up something with ui-sortable as well?

Comment: Yea, I can but that adds a level of complexity to the issue that isn't related to the current issue of $filter returning an array that is not an instance of  $firebaseArray. I think I need to use some variation of the extended $firebaseArray kato put together: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/bee266e31aa60cb0eed6